# How to create Dynamic Form fields in Django using MYSQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, crm

I want to create a Form in Django like the CRM system have(e.g SalesForce) where users can create or remove any number of fields.

My question is that How I will store data into the database?

1. Should I create columns in DB table for the individual field?
2. Should I have to store DATA in Json Or Array field?

Comment: you need to use JQuery with Ajax

Comment: Thanks @ZarakiKenpachi for the answer. but my question is not about frontend. It's related to the database structure.